# Unable to edit Odoo addon model field

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-15

Odoo version: 15.0
Addon: stock

stock.picking "priority" field is defined like this:

`priority=fields.Selection(PROCUREMENT_PRIORITIES, string='Priority', default='0',help="Products will be reserved first for the transfers with the highest priorities.")`

It uses PROCUREMENT_PRIORITIES as list of authorized values from stock.move:

`PROCUREMENT_PRIORITIES = [('0', 'Normal'), ('1', 'Urgent')]`

In version 13.0, PROCUREMENT_PRIORITIES was:

`PROCUREMENT_PRIORITIES = [('0', 'Not urgent'), ('1', 'Normal'), ('2', 'Urgent'), ('3', 'Very Urgent')]`

I want to put back this values in 15.0

I created a module to edit the priority field with a model models/stock_picking.py:

`
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
from odoo import fields, models

class Picking(models.Model):
  _inherit = 'stock.picking'

  priority = fields.Selection([('0', 'Not urgent'), ('1', 'Normal'), ('2', 'Urgent'), ('3', 'Very Urgent')])`
```

I installed the module successfully but I'm still unable to set the priority to 2 or 3 (through the priority widget):

`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 643, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: Wrong value for stock.picking.priority: '2'`
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [stock move priority](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/stock/models/stock_move.py#L194) depends on the picking priority:

```
priority = fields.Selection(
    PROCUREMENT_PRIORITIES, 'Priority', default='0',
    compute="_compute_priority", store=True)

@api.depends('picking_id.priority')
def _compute_priority(self):
    for move in self:
        move.priority = move.picking_id.priority or '0'
```

It should use the same selection values.